# The “Welcome to review queues” needs a space before the “you” link

Tags: bug, review-queues, typographical-error

I’m not sure exactly when I noticed it, but on iPhone 15.6.1, the word "by" is touching the word "you" (which is a link) in the "Welcome to the review queues" message.

[image: need a space]

I get fussy over aesthetics.

More detail on my iPhone.
iPhone 13 Pro Max with iOS 15.6.1 on T-Mobile USA.
I use the built in Safari browser with the following settings:

```
Prevent Cross-Site Tracking Enabled
Fraudulent Website Warning Enabled
Content Blockers Enabled (Firefox Focus)
```

Noticed today Sept 6th. The code around **you** from view source is:

```
<p>Meta Stack Overflow is moderated by <a href="https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/05/18/a-theory-of-moderation/">you</a>.</p>
```

Also reloading the page fixed it just now. So that’s unhelpful.

[image: sept-6th-2022]

Comment: What is the URL for this page? It seems worth checking whether the problem occurs on other platforms, and whether the space is actually missing in the HTML or if it's a CSS styling issue.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/review
However it appears fixed now.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/review This also looks good.

Comment: So it's fixed now?

Comment: It would appear so. Either it's intermittent or someone notice this and fixed it?

Comment: Given that it appeared to be "fixed" only minutes after you posted this bug report, I don't think someone noticed and fixed it. I rather suspect that it's an intermittent bug that is dependent on some unique circumstances. I'm going to mark this as "no-repro" for now. Do be sure to update if you (or anyone else, natch) sees and/or can reproduce this again. More details about the exact environment/context would always be useful.

Comment: @CodyGray it’s back. I’ve update with code snip. I’ve also saved the whole page source if you need me to find things in it.

Comment: Thanks for updating. I'm just an elected moderator, not a staff member, so I can't actually fix anything, but I've at least removed the "norepro" tag so hopefully a staff member will take a look.